# Convert a string JSON to a dictionary in Swift when curly quotes are used

Tags: swift, nsdictionary, quotes, nsjsonserialization

I have a string JSON, but it has fancy curly quotes in it which makes NSJSONSerialization fail.

```
let str = "{“title”:\"this is a “test” example\"}"

try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: str.data(using: .utf8)!) // Error
```

The quotes around `title` are curly double quotes and apparently JSONSerialization can not handle it and fails. A naive approach would be to simple replace all instances of the curly quote with a non-curly one. The problem with that approach is that it will change the curly quotes around `test` which shouldn't be changed! The quotes around `title` are OK to be changed but the ones around `test` should not.

What can I do to get around this issue?

Comment: Change `"{` to `{`, `}"` to `}` and `\"` to `"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this, you talk to whoever created the string, which does *not* contain JSON at the moment, and convince them to create a string that *does* contain JSON.

For JSON the rule is: If your parser can't parse it, then it's broken and you don't touch it.

The problem isn't that JSONSerialization cannot handle it. The problem is that JSONSerialization absolutely *must not* under any circumstances handle it. Because it's not JSON.

Comment: This issue happened in Swift only. If the Json is replied by an API, and other adopted program works fine, and Swift comes later with this error, the source cannot be modified for Swift.

JSONSerialization should fix this issue, it's a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

If curly quotes are only used for the keys, this regex will do the job:

```
let str = "{“title”:\"this is a “test” example\"}"

let strFixed = str.replacingOccurrences(
    of: #"“(.[^”]*)”:\"(.[^\"]*)\""#,
    with: "\"$1\":\"$2\"",
    options: .regularExpression
)

// It's strongly recommended to use try/catch instead of force unwrapping.
let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: strFixed.data(using: .utf8)!)
```

If we print `json`, we get the correct result:

```
{
    title = "this is a \U201ctest\U201d example";
}
```

---

### Explanation

```
“(.[^”]*)”:\"(.[^\"]*)\"
------------------------
“(.[^”]*)”                match everything between curly braces,
                          except the closing curling brace character

          :               separator between keys and values

           \"(.[^\"]*)\"  match everything between double quotes,
                          except the double quote character
```

```
    \"$1\":\"$2\"
    -------------
    \"$1\"         place the first captured group between double quotes

          :        separator between keys and values

           \"$2\"  place the second captured group between double quotes
```